# How can I disable keyboard shortcuts for jQuery UI date selector?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having a problem with the jQuery UI date selector, where when manually changing the date and hitting the enter key, the date selector date overrides the manual entry (the action I'm going for is a form submit).

I'd like to disable the keyboard shortcuts on the date selector, but haven't been able to find a way.

Comment: When I try with the built in demos I don't see that happen.  If I change the value in the text box and hit enter, the date picker automatically selects the correct date (based on what I've typed).  What exactly are you doing so I can test?

Comment: I'm thinking: are you trying to type date like spanish format? Spanish date format is dd/mm/yyyy, not mm/dd/yyyy. So datepicker could not work as you expect.

Comment: Have you loaded the Spanish localization?  I am using the default but I would imagine that it would work as expected if you have the correct localization selected. See here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can try to override that behaviour by assigning another keydown event handler to your input after datepicker initialization, and check for enter key there

```
$('#your_input_id').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) { 
      $('#your_form_id').submit();
      return false;
    }
});
```